# Creating key in Teradata

Tags: database-design, teradata, etl, data-warehouse

So as I was exploring Teradata more , I come up with a problem.
that is how to create surrogate keys fast and efficiently,

- using ETL tools like Informatica has limitation up to which it can generate keys like Sequence Generator can create up to 2 billion only, what after that ?
- Teradata has a facility of identity columns which can be used instead but will it not hamper parallelism like will it not insert data 1 row at a time and wait for the value of identity column to increment before inserting another row.
  if this is the case what one should do to handle this so that billions of rows can be inserted with a high performance.

Please help me if I am wrong , am new for this big technology of Teratada.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Informatica sequence generator has a limit of 9223372036854775807. You can use Alpha_numneric sequence for surrogate key like A1, A2... A9223372036854775807 and then B1,B2...B9223372036854775807. This will increase limit to 27*9223372036854775807 and this limit looks in-exhaustible for any data-set. For achieving this you need to set cycle property of sequence generator.

Comment: the problem is sequence generator is not fail proof say if you have commit interval as 1000 and you load fails at 199 the sequence generator will not roll back and next time generate values from 200  onward, creating gaps in keys generation.
now take this scenario up where you have commit interval of 1 million.

Comment: Then we can use Variable port for seq generation(Using Max+1) and can persist the last Max value by using any file or data base target. Please note that for big decimal calculations you have to enable high presicion in session config.

Answer (score 0):

Your mileage may vary, but we have been successful in incrementing surrogate keys by taking the `MAX()` of the surrogate key in the target table and then use then `ROW_NUMBER()` to increment the surrogate key for the new records being inserted into the target table.

The success of this approach will depend on your ETL approach. For us, we load our data to stage tables applying our transformations. Once the data has been loaded to staging the UPSERT of the data to the target tables is fairly straightforward using either `MERGE` or simple `UPDATE` / `INSERT` statements.